# Tag to use for questions related to narrow screen size mode

Tags: support, design, responsive-design

What tag should I use for narrow screen size site mode?
In this mode, the site design is slightly different from normal mode.

[mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) tag is marked as deprecated now.

As a suggestion, I used [narrow-width-design](/questions/tagged/narrow-width-design).

Comment: [responsive-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design) might be what you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [responsive-design](/questions/tagged/responsive-design). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) defines the term as:

> Responsive web design or responsive design is an approach to web design that aims to make web pages render well on a variety of devices and window or screen sizes from minimum to maximum display size to ensure usability and satisfaction.